# User current user on new Django class views forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using the django 1.3 on trunk, and start learning about class views.

I had this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('owner',)
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 20}),
        }

class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying, to get a form using model forms from django excluding the owner field, to get the field value after with the request.user property.

The form as it is, works. But how can make sure the ModelForm use request.user for the Project.owner field?

My first guess, was to override get_form_kwargs method from the view

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):

    # .....

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        self.initial['owner': self.request.user})
        kwargs = super(ProjectCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        return kwargs
```

But seem to have no effect on the data used by the model form

Comment: As I get no idea how to do this properly using the current django trunk version, I made a ticket with patch to solve this → http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14940

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`get_form_kwargs` is supposed to return a `dict` of arguments for your form - you set `self.initial`, but you didn't attach it to `kwargs`:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(ProjectCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
    kwargs['initial']['owner'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```